# How to add multiple edges in a single gremlin query?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

My scenario is to add multiple edges between vertices in a single query:

Assume the nodes below:
These are the labels and ids I have

**Users**:

4100

**Songs**:

4200

4355

4676

I have to establish edges between these vertices

```
4100 --> 4200, 
4100 --> 4355, 
4100 --> 4676.
```

We can do it normally by creating single edge between node.it is not a efficient method if we want to create edge between more than 50 vertices at a time. I am using Tinkerpop `3.0.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the vertex ids, it is very efficient to lookup by id. If you are using Gremlin Server, each request to the Gremlin Server is treated as a single transaction. You can pass the multiple statements in a Gremlin query on a single request (with bindings) rather than sending multiple requests. Separate the statements in the Gremlin query with semicolons.

```
l=[4200, 4355, 4676]; v=graph.vertices(4100).next(); l.each { v.addEdge("knows", graph.vertices(it).next()) }
```

Comment: The above query didn't work can you suggest for gremlin 3.0.1

Comment: I forgot the `next()` call. Updated my answer. Vertex lookup by id should be faster than an indexed lookup. It isn't clear from your question whether the ids you are talking about are the actual vertex ids or some other indexed property (which the other answers are assuming).

Comment: New to gremlin. I'm assuming "it" a reserved word. Hard to search for "it" on google. Can someone point me in the direction on some documentation on the use of each and "it"

Comment: `it` is the implicit parameter for the `each` closure. Those are both Groovy language constructs. `each` is for [iterating a list](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_iterating_on_a_list) where `it` is the current element.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem. With the C# SDK I do it like this:

```
g.V('4100')
.addE('knows').to(g.V('4200')).outV()
.addE('knows').to(g.V('4355')).outV()
.addE('knows').to(g.V('4676'))
```

Answer (score 8):

Using the latest Tinkerpop. You could do the following:

Create a sample graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open();
gremlin> graph.addVertex("User").property("id", 4100);
==>vp[id->4100]
gremlin> graph.addVertex("Song").property("id", 4200);
==>vp[id->4200]
gremlin> graph.addVertex("Song").property("id", 4355);
==>vp[id->4355]
gremlin> graph.addVertex("Song").property("id", 4676);
==>vp[id->4676]
```

Now add the edges in a single traversal:

```
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().hasLabel("User").as("a").
         V().hasLabel("Song").
         addE("edge to song").from("a");
==>e[8][0-edge to song->2]
==>e[9][0-edge to song->4]
==>e[10][0-edge to song->6]
```

[This](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addedge-step) shows another example of using `addE` within a traversal as a side effect.

Comment: I don't think this approach will work with `3.0.1` as the second `V()` is not supported in that version, I think it is only supported from `3.1.x` onwards. If you are stuck with `3.0.1` I think you will need to do two traversals. One to get the ids and the second to build the edges as suggested by Jason in the other answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
gremlin> songs = g.V().has("album","albumname")).toList();user = g.V().has('fullName','arunkumar').next(); songs.each{user.addEdge("in",it)} 

gremlin> g.E() //check the edge
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will work but is more than a single gremlin query.

Comment: changed to single query :)

Comment: Sorry but putting it on the same line does not make it a single query. I.e. `songs = g.V().has("album","albumname")).toList();` Thats one query. `user = g.V().has('fullName','arunkumar').next();` and thats the second. In fact you are doing 3 traversals in this case, which is inefficient.