# Add multiple edges in a single gremlin query using vertex ids

Tags: groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I am using gremlin REST server in my application and I want to create multiple edges to a vertex in a single query. I have the list of vertex ids from where to create edges to a single vertex.

For eg.- g.V(12,13,14,15).addEdge('uses', g.V(100))

I have tried many traversal steps but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

You should look at the [`addE()` step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addedge-step) - here's one example for you can do it:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V(2,3,4,5,6).as('a').V(1).addE('likes').to('a')
==>e[13][1-likes->2]
==>e[14][1-likes->3]
==>e[15][1-likes->4]
==>e[16][1-likes->5]
==>e[17][1-likes->6]
```

Comment: gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('earms_user')
==>v[19660804192]
==>v[24576008272]
==>v[19660804216]
==>v[19660804248]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('earms_group')
==>v[18432004112]
==>v[20889604240]
gremlin> g.V(19660804192,24576008272,19660804216).as('a').V(18432004112).addE('eu_eg').to('a')
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.V() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [18432004112]
Possible solutions: by(groovy.lang.Closure), is(java.lang.Object), any(), sum(), min(), max()

Comment: gremlin> graph2 = TinkerFactory.createModern()  
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]  
gremlin> g = graph2.traversal()  
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]  
gremlin> g.V(2,3,4,5,6).as('a').V(1).addE('likes').to('a')  
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.V() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]
Possible solutions: by(groovy.lang.Closure), is(java.lang.Object), any(), sum(), min(), max()

Comment: what graph implementation are you using? and what version of tinkerpop?

Comment: got it working using this - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185325/how-to-add-multiple-edges-in-a-single-gremlin-query).  Is this correct?

Comment: I am using titan graph db and tinkerpop3.

Comment: I have another doubt for which I have posted another question. Please check if you can answer that too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027444/gremlin-only-add-a-vertex-if-it-doesnt-exists

Comment: You can do what is in that link, but that is a single script, not a single traversal. If that's not a problem for you then you I guess you are fine, but ultimately it would be best to have a single traversal to do that work. If you are using Titan it could be that you have an older version that doesn't support the form of traversal I suggested. {{addE()}} should still work though in some capacity. If I were you, I'd study that a bit more.

Comment: You might also consider using JanusGraph - http://janusgraph.org/ - so that you can get a newer version of TinkerPop to use.