# CosmosDB Graph : "upsert" query pattern

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am new to Gremlin query language.
I have to insert data on a Cosmos DB graph (using Gremlin.Net package), whether the Vertex (or Edge) already exists in the graph or not. If the data exists, I only need to update the properties.
I wanted to use this kind of pattern:

```
g.V().hasLabel('event').has('id','1').tryNext().orElseGet {g.addV('event').has('id','1')}
```

But it is not supported by Gremlin.Net / Cosmos DB graph API. Is there a way to make a kind of upsert query in a single query ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this but I think that the TinkerPop community has generally settled on this approach:

```
g.V().has('event','id','1').
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV('event').property('id','1'))
```

Basically, it looks for the "event" with `has()` and uses `fold()` step to coerce to a list. The list will either be empty or have a `Vertex` in it. Then with `coalesce()`, it tries to `unfold()` the list and if it has a `Vertex` that is immediately returned otherwise, it does the `addV()`.

If the idea is to update existing properties if the element is found, just add `property()` steps after the `coalesce()`:

```
g.V().has('event','id','1').
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV('event').property('id','1')).
  property('description','This is an event')
```

If you need to know if the vertex returned was "new" or not then you could do something like this:

```
g.V().has('event','id','1').
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold().
           project('vertex','exists').
             by(identity()).
             by(constant(true)),
           addV('event').property('id','1').
           project('vertex','exists').
             by(identity()).
             by(constant(false)))
```

Additional reading on this topic can be found on this question: "[Why do you need to fold/unfold using coalesce for a conditional insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785067/1831717)"

Also note that optional edge insertion is described here: "[Add edge if not exist using gremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447622/1831717)".

As a final note, while this question was asked regarding CosmosDB, the answer generally applies to all TinkerPop-enabled graphs. Of course, how a graph optimizes this Gremlin is a separate question. If a graph has native upsert capabilities, that capability may or may not be used behind the scenes of this Gremlin so there may be better ways to implement upsert by way of the graphs systems native API (of course, choosing that path reduces the portability of your code).

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.0, the `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` pattern has been largely [replaced by the new steps](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_mergev_and_mergee) of `mergeV()` and `mergeE()` which greatly simplify the Gremlin required to do an upsert-like operation. Under 3.6.0 and newer versions, you would replace the first example with:

```
g.mergeV([(label): 'event', id: '1'])
```

or perhaps better, treat the property key named "id" as an actual vertex identifier of `T` (I've added the property key of "name" to help with the example):

```
g.mergeV([(label): 'event', (id): '1', name: 'stephen'])
```

The above will search for a vertex with the `T.label`, `T.id` and "name" in the `Map`. If it finds it, it is returned. If it does not find it, the `Vertex` is created using those values. If you have the `T.id` it may be even better to do:

```
g.mergeV([(id): '1']).
    option(onCreate, [(label): 'event', name: 'stephen'])
```

In this way, you limit the search criteria to just the identifier which is enough to uniquely identify it and avoids additional filters and then if the verted is not found the `onCreate` is triggered to use the supplied `Map` to create the vertex in conjunction with the search criteria `Map`.

Comment: What if I want the query to also tell me if the node already existed or was just created? What I came up with so far is : `g.V('1234').fold().as('existing').coalesce(unfold(), addV().property(id,'1234')).as('result').select('existing','result')` which works nicely, returning  `{ 'existing': [], result: { ... } }` *when the node is created*, but duplicates the returned payload if the node already exists: `{ 'existing': [{ /*node payload*/ }], result: { /*same node payload again*/ } }`

Comment: I think I found a better way (just learned out about `store()`):  `g.V('1235').fold().store('existing').coalesce(unfold(), addV().property(id,'1235').store('new')).cap('existing','new')`. This way, either 'existing' or 'new' is always empty. Let me know if there's an even better way of exposing a boolean flag and a single property for the payload.

Comment: your approach is good though it's nice to avoid side-effects if you can. updated my answer with a side-effect free traversal and a simple boolean value as the return for whether the vertex was added or not.

Comment: That's great! Thank you for sharing. What about avoiding side effects? Is this due to the more philosophical quest for purity in functional programming, or does it have measurable, umm, side effects?

Comment: It's nice to read Gremlin left to right without having to refer back to some earlier point in the traversal so from a readability perspective, I tend to think side-effects makes Gremlin harder to follow. You also incur additional processing and memory costs on your traversal for requiring side-effect constructs which is perhaps more of a reason to try to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually guys, here's how you do it!

This way you can Add/Update 2 Vertexes and an Edge and associate them at the same time!

```
g.V().
    has('Person', 'name', 'Ben').fold().
        coalesce(unfold().property('age', 25), 
        __.addV('Person').property('name','Ben').property('age',25)).store('start').
    V().has('Person','name','Robert').fold().
        coalesce(unfold().property('age', 41), 
        __.addV('Person').property('name','Robert').property('age',41)).
    coalesce(__.outE('link').has('id', 3).property('weight', 11), 
    __.addE('link').property('id', 3).property('weight', 10).to(select("start").unfold()))
```