# Add or get vertex in Azure Cosmos DB Graph API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Using Gremlin, I can create a vertex in an Azure Cosmos DB graph by issuing

```
g.addV('the-label').property('id', 'the-id')
```

and subsequently find it using

```
g.V('the-label').has('id', 'the-id')
```

However, I haven't found a way to issue a query that will insert the node if it is missing, and just get the reference to it if it already exists. Is there a way?

---

My concrete use case is that I want to add an edge between two nodes, regardless of whether those nodes (or the edge, for that matter) exist already or not, in a single query. I tried [this upsert approach](http://teknosrc.com/upsert-gremlin-query-language-titan/), but apparently Cosmos DB does not support Groovy closures, so it won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "upsert pattern" is relatively well defined and accepted at this point. It is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758568/1831717). If you want to extend that to also add an edge, that's possible too:

```
g.V().has('event','id','1').
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV('event').property('id','1')).as('start').
  coalesce(outE('link').has('id','3'),
           coalesce(V().has('event','id','2'), 
                    addV('event').property('id','2')).
                    addE('link').from('start').property('id','3'))
```

If that looks a bit complex you can definitely simplify with a [Gremlin DSL](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#dsl) (though I'm not sure that CosmosDB supports Gremlin bytecode at this point). Here's an [example](https://github.com/datastax/graph-examples/blob/kv-2.0/killrvideo/dsl/java/src/main/java/com/killrvideo/KillrVideoApp.java#L68-L71) with even more complex upsert logic simplified by a DSL. It's discussed in this [blog post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/gremlin-dsls-in-java-with-dse-graph) in more detail.

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.0, the `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` pattern has been largely [replaced by the new steps](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_mergev_and_mergee) of `mergeV()` and `mergeE()` which greatly simplify the Gremlin required to do an upsert-like operation.

Comment: Current Cosmos does not have support for bytecode, so no DSL, but I have been told they are working on it

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this.

http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#coalesce-step

You can try

g.Inject(0).coalesce(__.V().has('id', 'the-id'), addV('the-label').property('id', 'the-id'))

btw, you won't able to find the vertex using g.V('the-label').has('id', 'the-id').

g.V() accepts vertex id as parameters and not vertex labels.