# Can threads see each other's changes in multi-threaded transactions?

Tags: tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I'm employing [multi-threaded transactions](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/transactions/#multi-threaded-transactions) as described by JanusGraph docs. Each of my threads contributes to building a directory tree. Before inserting a new vertex for a specific directory, each thread first checks if such a vertex already exists within the same query. Vertexes are only inserted with `.orElseGet` if no existing one can be found.

```
Vertex vertex = graph.traversal().V()
    .hasLabel(VertexLabels.DIRECTORY)
    .has(PropertyKeys.PATH, directory.path())
    .tryNext()
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        return graph.addVertex(
            T.label, VertexLabels.DIRECTORY,
            PropertyKeys.PATH, directory.path());
    });
```

Technically, this should prevent duplicates assuming that all threads operate within the same transactional scope. I do however encounter duplicates. The docs don't seem to give any answers regarding this issue. Can you confirm whether multi-threaded transactions operate within the same scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-threaded transactions operate in the same scope, but I suppose it remains possible for the threads to race if you haven't configured a [unique constraint](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.2/basics/index-performance/#index-uniqueness) on `PropertyKeys.PATH`. Doing so does mean that [locking](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.2/advanced-topics/eventual-consistency/#data-consistency-without-locks) would be enabled which might slow down your ingestion rate but will ensure uniqueness.

As a side note please consider avoiding use of the Graph API (`graph.addVertex()`) and sticking to pure Gremlin - the "get or create" pattern is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758568/1831717).