# Gremlin - Upsert of vertex not working with coalesce

Tags: gremlin, upsert, amazon-neptune

I am new to gremlin and have a very simple case where I need to check this:

- If vertex exists

  - Update properties
- Else

  - Add vertex with properties

I am using the Java API for this.

My code:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Entity").has("identifier", "123").fold()
.coalesce(
    __.unfold(),
    __.addV("Entity")
        .property("identifier", "123")
        .property("value", "A")
        .property("action", "add")
    )
.property("value", "A")
.property("action", "update")
.iterate();
```

I know that this is a very simple case and I referred to the example given in [[CosmosDB Graph : "upsert" query pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758417/cosmosdb-graph-upsert-query-pattern][1])

But it doesn't work. If the vertex doesn't exist, it is added with the properties but the properties are are updated also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write Gremlin you need to think in terms of streams. `V()` produces a stream of all vertices in the graph. Envision each item in that stream hitting `hasLabel()` and `has()` filters to be paired away until they hit the reducing step of `fold()` which produces a `List` with vertices that match the filter criteria or, if there are none, it simple produces an empty list which becomes the new object in the stream.

From there `coalesce()` produces an if-then sort of case where the first child stream provided to it that returns a value ends up being exhausted and the remaining child streams ignored. Therefore, if `unfold()` which takes the `List` with vertices produced by `fold()` contains a vertex, then it is provided to the stream and that vertex exists and `coalesce()` thus produces that existing vertex and goes on to the final two steps of `property("value", "A").property("action", "update")`. If the `List` is empty then the `unfold()` stream produces no objects and goes to the next child stream which starts with `addV()`. The `addV()` stream will obviously produce a new `Vertex` with the specified properties, but then `coalesce()` as its parent will produce that newly added vertex to the stream and it too will continue to those final two steps and thus overwrite the property values you provided to `addV()`.

If you want to have two separate paths, then you might do something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Entity").has("identifier", "123").fold()
.coalesce((Traversal)
    __.unfold()
        .property("value", "A")
        .property("action", "update"),
    __.addV("Entity")
        .property("identifier", "123")
        .property("value", "A")
        .property("action", "add")
    )
.iterate();
```

More information about upserting vertices can be found on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758568/1831717)

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.0, the `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` pattern has been largely [replaced by the new steps](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_mergev_and_mergee) of `mergeV()` and `mergeE()` which greatly simplify the Gremlin required to do an upsert-like operation. Under 3.6.0 and newer versions, you would write:

```
g.mergeV([(label): 'Entity', identifier: '123', value: 'A']).
  option(onCreate, [action: 'add']).
  option(onMatch, [action: 'update'])
```

Comment: The above code doesn't compile due to error: The method coalesce(Traversal<?,E2>...) in the type GraphTraversal<Vertex,List<Vertex>> is not applicable for the arguments (GraphTraversal<Object,Object>, GraphTraversal<Object,Vertex>)

Comment: You can cast your way out of that problem - see my updated answer

Comment: insert works but update not working

Answer (score 0):

Whether the vertex exists or not coalesce will either return the existing vertex or the newly created one. In either case the property setting steps that come after coalesce will be applied to whatever flowed out of it. If you only want the changes after coalesce applied to an existing vertex put them after the unfold step instead.