# Update a vertex and a all its child vertexes and edges

Tags: python, graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I have JSON entities like this one that I insert in the graph as edges and vertexes, as you can see, each entities are already in an highly relational format.

```py
person = {
    "summary": "Unix System Administrator at National Bank of Canada",
    "id": "P6ZiIHhJ-PhON9W6UgeFwfA",
    "name": "Patrick",
    "type": "Person",
    "employments": [
        {
            "isCurrent": True,
            "employer": {
                "Name": "Commercial bank located in Canada",
                "type": "Corporation"
            },
            "title": "Unix System Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "skills": [
        {
            "name": "string"
        }
    ],
    "locations": [
        {
            "country": {
                "name": "Canada",
                "type": "AdministrativeArea"
            }
        }
    ],
    "someVertex": {
        "k": "v"
    }
}
```

The resulting graph:
[image]

My problem is that, in the future, I might receive a new json for that same person where I need to "update it" in the graph if something changed and making sure to delete any child vertexes that no longer exist. kind of like the upsert but on all the child nodes and edges.

Right now, I add the root id as a property on every child elements so I can find them all and delete them later. Is there another way to do this?

My actual process:

1. Add all verticles and edges from the python dict recursively, nested dicts all become vertexes and an edge is added between it and the parent.

```py
def add_vertex(g, label, dct, entity_id):
   vertex = g.addV(label).property('entity_id', entity_id)
   add_properties(g, vertex, dct, entity_id)
   return vertex


def add_properties(g, vertex, dct, entity_id):
   # Add properties
   for k, v in dct.items():
       if type(v) in [str, bool, int, float]:
           vertex = vertex.property(k, v)

       elif v and isinstance(v, list) and type(v[0]) in [str, bool, int, float]:
           for literal in v:
               vertex = vertex.property(Cardinality.set_, k, literal)

   vertex = vertex.next()

   # Add child vertexes and edges to them
   for k, v in dct.items():
       if isinstance(v, dict):
           nested_vertex = add_vertex(g, k, v, entity_id)
           add_edge(g, k, vertex, nested_vertex, entity_id)

       elif v and isinstance(v, list) and isinstance(v[0], dict):
           for nested_v in v:
               nested_vertex = add_vertex(g, k, nested_v, entity_id)
               add_edge(g, k, vertex, nested_vertex, entity_id)


def add_edge(g, name, from_v, to_v, entity_id):
   g.addE(name).property('entity_id', entity_id).from_(from_v).to(to_v).iterate()


add_vertex(g, 'Person', person , person['id'])
```

2. If I receive the person with the same id, imagine the vertex "someVertex" is now gone in the dict, how can I "upsert" the whole tree of vertexes and edges that originally come from this person so that that this vertex is removed? For now I delete all elements with the property "entity_id" that I added in the previous step.

```py
if g.V().has(entity_type, 'id', entity_id).hasNext():
    g.V().has('entity_id', entity_id).drop().iterate()
    add_vertex(g, entity_type, entity, entity_id)
```

Comment: Are you saying that your upserting approach leaves you with orphaned child vertices that need to be deleted later? Is there some reason you can't delete the children as you do the upsert? Perhaps you could describe/show that process a bit more?

Comment: @stephenmallette I added some information, I am new the gremlin and graphs, maybe there's something to improve about my first step too as it is pretty slow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an "entity_id" property to all vertices isn't a horrible approach to finding all the ones to drop. A more graph oriented way would be to simply follow the edges of the parent recursively dropping all vertices that you find:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV().property(id, 'A').as('a').
......1>   addV().property(id, 'B').as('b').
......2>   addV().property(id, 'C').as('c').
......3>   addV().property(id, 'E').as('e').
......4>   addV().property(id, 'F').as('f').
......5>   addE('hasParent').from('a').to('b').
......6>   addE('hasParent').from('b').to('c').
......7>   addE('hasParent').from('c').to('e').
......8>   addE('hasParent').from('e').to('f').iterate()
gremlin> g.V().has(id,'B').
......1>   emit().
......2>   repeat(out()).
......3>   aggregate('x').
......4>   select('x').unfold().
......5>   drop()
gremlin> g.V().elementMap()
==>[id:A,label:vertex]
```

I chose to `aggregate()` them first as most graphs would prefer that approach I think (as opposed to dropping as you traverse), but you could try that as well to avoid collecting the side-effect `List` of "x".

There are methods to updating graph structure in place with more true upsert style semantics. You have a fairly robust sort of tree structure though so I sense that will make for a fairly chunky and complex bit of Gremlin. It's possible that dropping it all and adding it back makes the most sense in your case - hard to say. That pattern for upserts is described in many places here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758417/cosmosdb-graph-upsert-query-pattern) and [other places](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) you might search around for.