# Gremin mergeV() Upsert: knowing whether the vertex was added or not(side-effect free)

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

In [CosmosDB Graph : "upsert" query pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758417/cosmosdb-graph-upsert-query-pattern/49758568#49758568), there was an awesome discussion of using `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` style pattern for upserting vertex, and knowing whether the vertex has been added or obtained:

```
g.V().has('event','id','1').
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold().
           project('vertex','exists').
             by(identity()).
             by(constant(true)),
           addV('event').property('id','1').
           project('vertex','exists').
             by(identity()).
             by(constant(false)))
```

The post also made the update that there was a more advanced pattern using `mergeV()`. I wonder if we can "translate" the above to the more advanced `mergeV()` pattern?

Any help/insight is much appreciated!

The new `mergeV()` pattern seems to expect a list as the inputs, so i am not sure how to map that from the original queries.

Comment: Are you using CosmosDB as your database? If so, I believe only a fairly old version of Gremlin that does not include `mergeV` is supported. You can definitely translate the example in the question to one that uses `mergeV`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am planning to use AWS Neptune as my DB, so yes, I am pretty sure that `mergeV` is supported. Specifically, my question is more on how to translate the part of `project(...).by(...)` part into the new `mergeV` syntax, as I didn't find any examples in the documentation. I am pretty new to Gremlin - hopefully my question does make sense, and any thoughts are greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - happy to help with that - I'll try to put together a little example (unless someone else beats me to it :-) )

Comment: Hey Kelvin, thanks a lot for the help so far! I wonder if you're familiar with gremlin-go as well? I have encountered a follow-up issue while working with gremlin-go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77624393/how-to-do-constant-in-gremlin-go. Would greatly appreciate your thoughts on this, when you get a chance! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll take a look. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: Great! Thanks again for taking the effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onMatch` and `onCreate` to know what happened during the `mergeV` search. Here is one way to build on that to generate a result similar to the one described in the question.

```java
g.mergeV([T.id:'1']).
    option(Merge.onMatch,sideEffect(constant(true).store('found')).constant([:])).
    option(Merge.onCreate,sideEffect(constant(false).store('found')).constant([:])).
  project('id','status').
    by(id()).
    by(select('found').unfold())
```

As the vertex with an ID of '1' does exist, when run, this is what the query returns:

```
{'id': '1', 'status': True}
```

Strictly speaking in this case you don't need the `sideEffect` wrapper, but I find it cleaner as it isolates that work from the rest of the `onMatch` steps.

Comment: Awesome, really appreciate the effort, it works on my end! I've made slight adjustments based on the response. To retain it for future reference, it is ```g.mergeV([(label): 'event', id: '1']). option(Merge.onMatch,sideEffect(constant(true).store('found')).constant([:])). option(Merge.onCreate,sideEffect(constant(false).store('found')).constant([:])). project('id','status'). by(id()). by(select('found').unfold()) ```