# How to do "constant([:])" in gremlin-go

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I previously received helpful guidance from Kelvin in a Stack Overflow post (linked here: [Gremin mergeV() Upsert: knowing whether the vertex was added or not(side-effect free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587723/gremin-mergev-upsert-knowing-whether-the-vertex-was-added-or-notside-effect)) regarding the successful execution of a Groovy query using Gremlin's mergeV syntax. This query allowed me to determine whether a vertex was added or obtained without any side effects. Now, I'm encountering issues when attempting to translate that Groovy code into Go code.
The Groovy code, which functions correctly in my Gremlin console, is as follows:

```
g.mergeV([(label): 'principal', spiffe_id: '1']). 
option(Merge.onCreate,[creat_at:'10/23/2023', update_at:'11/23/2023']).
option(Merge.onMatch,sideEffect(constant(true).store('found')).constant([:])).
option(Merge.onCreate,sideEffect(constant(false).store('found')).constant([:])).
project('spiffe_id','status'). by(id()). by(select('found').unfold())
```

However, when attempting to convert this code into Golang, I encounter an error:

```
code:244 message:class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to 
class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element
```

Here's the Golang code I'm using:

```golang
var __ = gremlingo.T__

steps := graph.g.MergeV(map[interface{}]interface{}{
        gremlingo.T.Label: "principal", "spiffe_id": "1"}).
        Option(gremlingo.Merge.OnCreate, map[interface{}]interface{}{
            "created_at": "10/23/2023", "updated_at": "10/23/2023"}).
        Option(gremlingo.Merge.OnCreate, __.SideEffect(__.Constant(false).Store("found")).Constant(map[interface{}]interface{}{})).
        Option(gremlingo.Merge.OnMatch, __.SideEffect(__.Constant(true).Store("found")).Constant(map[interface{}]interface{}{})).
        Project("principal", "status").By(__.Identity()).By(__.Select("found").Unfold())
queryResult, err := steps.ElementMap().ToList()
...
```

Upon attempting to comment out the section involving `Constant(map[interface{}]interface{}{})`, I encountered a new error: `java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to class java.util.Map`. It seems that the issue arises from the `constant([:])` operation in Groovy, which I attempted to replicate in Golang as `Constant(map[interface{}]interface{}{})`.

It appears that during the serialization and deserialization process, there's a mismatch where the gremlin Element structure is attempting to utilize a Java LinkedHashMap. I'm uncertain whether this is due to a mistake in my Go code or if it is due to an incompatibility between the gremlin-go client and the Java server.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is that requests for Groovy and Golang are not equivalent.

Error

> code:244 message:class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to
> class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element

thrown by step `ElementMap()` because it cannot work with input other than `Element`, but receive `Map` produced by previous `Project`.
In Groovy example there is no `ElementMap()`.

Therefore, a possible solution is to remove `ElementMap()`. Or, if you need it, then move inside `Project`
`Project("principal", "status").By(__.Identity().ElementMap()).By(__.Select("found").Unfold())`

P.S. Tested on Gremlin Server 3.7.1

Comment: Appreciate the help, Valentyn!!! I attempted the solution on my end, and while it compiled successfully, it seems that my Go code is disregarding the initial OnCreate condition when I have two chained OnCreate conditions. After implementing the change in my Go code, the resulting output overlooks the "created_at" and "updated_at" fields that I intended to set. The same Groovy code doesn't seem to have this problem. Do you have any insights into what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Only the last Merge.onCreate option works, so solution is to combine them into one

`Option(gremlingo.Merge.OnCreate, __.SideEffect(__.Constant(false).Store("found")).Constant(map[interface{}]interface{}{
            "created_at": "10/23/2023", "updated_at": "10/23/2023"}).`
   
Same should be for Gremlin Console.

Comment: Awesome! I just tested on both `gremlin-go` and gremlin console using Groovy, and they all worked! Thank you again for sharing your knowledge, Valentyn, this has been quite helpful!