# Adding Multiple Unique Vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I want to write a single gremlin query that will create multiple vertices, but only does so if they are all unique. I know I can use the get or addV method by using coalesce step mentioned in the comments.

`g.V().has('com.demo.test', '__type', 'Namespace').fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('com.demo.test').property('__type', 'Namespace'))`

This will hadd a single vertex only if it does not exist already. What if i want to do this same procedure for multiple edges and vertices all in a single query? My goal is that if one of the vertices/edges is not unique, none of them are created. However I understand that may not be possible so all answers are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gremlin - only add a vertex if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027444/gremlin-only-add-a-vertex-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: @jason neptune does not allow lambda functions

Comment: look at the last code block in the answer, _The general way to handle a "get or create" in a single traversal is to do something like this:_ `g.V().has('person','name','bill').fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('person').property('name','bill'))`

Comment: Using your parameters, `g.V().has('com.demo.test', '__type', 'Namespace').fold().coalesce(unfold(), addV('com.demo.test').property('__type', 'Namespace'))`

Comment: Is there anyway I can do a multi vertex/edge creation single query with this logic?

Comment: Yes, edit your original question and add this new one.

Comment: I've done as you have asked

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution. This works but there might be a better way to do it.

```
g.V().coalesce(
  V().has(label,'Namespace61'),
  addV('Namespace61')).
coalesce(
  V().has(label,'Namespace76'),
  addV('Namespace76')).
coalesce(
  V().has(label,'Namespace74'),
  addV('Namespace74')
).dedup()
```

Comment: That looks fine. It's the same approach used in this post https://groups.google.com/d/msg/janusgraph-dev/KfCjSbwzh9E/LBVgIzo4BgAJ

Comment: Do not do this!  It looks innocent enough, but `g.V()` is a problem.  This will read every vertex in the database and then try to add a new vertex for each existing one.  It's too bad you can't just start with `g.coalesce(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an idempotent way to create several vertices in a single command.  I use Cosmos DB's Gremlin API, and the typical solution using fold...coalesce...unfold doesn't work when chained together.  Through some experimentation, I came up with this alternative whose complexity is linear as you add more vertices.  I'm using `inject()` to artificially create a "source" for the coalesce to build from.

```
g.inject("0")
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk1','00']), addV('MyV').property('id','00').property('partitionKey','pk1')).as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk1','01']), addV('MyV').property('id','01').property('partitionKey','pk1')).as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk1','02']), addV('MyV').property('id','02').property('partitionKey','pk1')).as('x')
.select('x')
```

For those unconcerned about partition keys, that looks like this:

```
g.inject("0")
  .coalesce(__.V('00'), addV('MyV').property('id','00')).as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V('01'), addV('MyV').property('id','01')).as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V('02'), addV('MyV').property('id','02')).as('x')
.select('x')
```