# Gremlin Coalesce To Add Multiple Vertices and Edges

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Right now I am able to generate a query to create as many vertices and edges as I want.

e.g.

```
g.V().
addV('vert1').as('a').
addV('vert2').as('b').
addE('has').from('a').to('b')
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This works. Easy enough right? Now lets create a gremlin query that only creates these vertices if their label is unique. Then create an edge between the two.

```
g.V().has(label,'vert1').fold().
    coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV('vert1')
    ).as('a').
    V().has(label,'vert2').fold().
    coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV('vert2')
    ).as('b').
    addE('has').from('a').to('b')
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^This does not work

hopefully you can understand what I am trying to do though. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: the first line `g.V().addV('vert1').as('a').addV('vert2').as('b').addE('has').from('a').to('b')` does not work for me in AWS Neptune. Any idea why? Seems like the `.as()` is invalid syntax

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: `g.V().addV('vert1').as('a').addV('vert2').as('b').addE('has').from('a').to('b')`
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. You' cant really see it here, but the arrow is pointing to the as() clause.

Comment: get rid of the .V() at the beginning. It will look like g.addV('vert1').as('a').addV('vert2').as('b').addE('has').from('a').to('b')

Comment: it still doesn't work. I think it is because of Gremlin Python? Maybe the `as` is a special command

Comment: Looking at the source code here https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/process/graph_traversal.py I am unable to see the as step defined. This is very odd, not sure why this might be. This could be a question for @stephenmalette. Are there any alternative languages you could use? I know gremlin.net is very well developed.

Comment: @cryanbhu after further investigation of the python traversal class it looks like the step is defined as as_. try `g.addV('vert1').as_('a').addV('vert2').as_('b').addE('has').from('a').to('b')`. Happy coding!

Comment: Didn't realize i could just check out the gremlin-python code directly there. Thank you! @austin-malpede

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a `fold()` which is a `ReducingBarrierStep` that follows after your step label at `as('a')` and the path history to "a" is lost after that step. You can read more about this aspect of Gremlin [here](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#rbarriers).

You just need to re-write your query to account for that - one way might be to just `aggregate()` the value of "a" rather than simply naming the step "a":

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has(label,'vert1').fold().
......2>   coalesce(unfold(),
......3>            addV('vert1')).aggregate('a').
......4>   V().has(label,'vert2').fold().
......5>   coalesce(unfold(),
......6>            addV('vert2')).as('b').
......7>   select('a').unfold().
......8>   addE('has').to('b')
==>e[2][0-has->1]
```

If you need to return all the elements, just `project()` the returned edge and transform the results as necessary:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has(label,'vert1').fold().
......2>   coalesce(unfold(),
......3>            addV('vert1')).aggregate('a').
......4>   V().has(label,'vert2').fold().
......5>   coalesce(unfold(),
......6>            addV('vert2')).as('b').
......7>   select('a').unfold().
......8>   addE('has').to('b').
......9>   project('e','in','out').
.....10>     by().
.....11>     by(inV()).
.....12>     by(outV())
==>[e:e[2][0-has->1],in:v[1],out:v[0]]
```

Of course, using a `select()` at the end might not be so bad either:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   has(label,'vert1').fold().
......2>   coalesce(unfold(),
......3>            addV('vert1')).aggregate('a').
......4>   V().has(label,'vert2').fold().
......5>   coalesce(unfold(),
......6>            addV('vert2')).as('b').
......7>   select('a').unfold().
......8>   addE('has').to('b').as('x').
......9>   select('a','b','x')
==>[a:[v[0]],b:v[1],x:e[2][0-has->1]]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have 'a' stored unfolded so that the edge could be constructed like addE('has').from('a').to('b')?

Comment: To answer my comment above it looks like addE('has').from(select('a').unfold()).to(select('b').unfold) is what I am looking for. Thanks for your help Stephan. You are the GRAPH KING

Comment: For the solution you came up with is there any way to have everything that was created returned? You can see that e[2][0-has->1] is your return value. What if I want both the vertices returned? Hopefully there's an alternative to adding select('a','b') to the end.

Comment: updated my answer - i'd just `project()` the resulting edge. i think your idea to `select()` is not so bad either. might be the most efficient approach actually, as those elements are already in memory.

Comment: hi @stephenmallette Can you help me answer my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54265985/create-if-not-exist-vertex-and-edge-in-1-query-gremlin

Answer (score 0):

I, too, was looking for an idempotent way to create several vertices in a single command and get the results back.  (I use Cosmos DB's Gremlin API, and the typical solution using fold...coalesce...unfold doesn't work when chained together.)

Through some experimentation, I came up with this alternative whose complexity is linear as you add more vertices.  I'm using `inject()` to artificially create a "source" for the first invocation of `coalesce()`.

```
g.inject("0")
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk1','00']), addV('MyV')
    .property('id','00')
    .property('partitionKey','pk1')).as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk1','01']), addV('MyV')
    .property('id','01')
    .property('partitionKey','pk1'))
    .as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk1','02']), addV('MyV')
    .property('id','02')
    .property('partitionKey','pk1'))
    .as('x')
.select('x')
```

For those unconcerned about partition keys, that looks like this:

```
g.inject("0")
  .coalesce(__.V('00'), addV('MyV').property('id','00')).as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V('01'), addV('MyV').property('id','01')).as('x')
  .coalesce(__.V('02'), addV('MyV').property('id','02')).as('x')
.select('x')
```

Additionally, we can create any number of edges between new vertices at the same time by providing unique labels (with `as()`).

```
g.inject("0")
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk2','05']), addV('MyV').property('id','05')
    .property('partitionKey','pk2')
    .property('ABC','123467890'))
    .as('x').as('a')
  .coalesce(__.V(['pk2','06']), addV('MyV').property('id','06')
    .property('partitionKey','pk2')
    .property('ABC','123467890'))
    .as('x')
  .coalesce(g.E(['pk2','07']), addE('MyE').property('id','07').from('a'))
    .as('x')
.select('x')
```