# Create if not exist Vertex and Edge in 1 Gremlin Query

Tags: graph, gremlin, janusgraph

I find the following code to create edge if it has not existed yet.

```
g.V().hasLabel("V1")
.has("userId", userId).as("a")
.V().hasLabel("V1").has("userId", userId2)
.coalesce(
        bothE("link").where(outV().as("a")),
        addE("link").from("a")
)
```

It works fine but I want to create both vertices and edge if they are not existed in 1 query.

I try the following code with new graph, it just create new vertices but no relation between them.

```
g.V().hasLabel("V1")
.has("userId", userId).fold()
.coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV("V1").property("userId", userId1)
).as("a")
.V().hasLabel("V1").has("userId", userId2).fold()
.coalesce(
        unfold(),
        addV("V1").property("userId", userId2)
)
.coalesce(
        bothE("link").where(outV().as("a")),
        addE("link").from("a")
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Kuppitz in [JanusGraph google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/janusgraph-users/AS-_W9SaWS4/rJTInVJ_CwAJ). I found out the solution. I re-post it here for anyone who need it.

There are two issues in your query. The first one is the reason why it doesn't work as expected: the fold() step. Using fold() will destroy the path history, but you can easily work around it, by doing that part in a child traversal:

```
g.V().has("V1","userId", userId1).fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV("V1").property("userId", userId1)).as("a").
  map(V().has("V1","userId", userId2).fold()).
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV("V1").property("userId", userId2))
  coalesce(inE("link").where(outV().as("a")),
           addE("link").from("a"))
```

The second issue is the combination of bothE and outV. You should rather use `bothE/otherV`, `outE/inV` or `inE/outV`.

Answer (score 1):

I used the approach suggested by  [@thangdc94](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5016540/thangdc94) (thanks!) and found that the "map" step takes a long time, this query worked much faster (X20) for me:

```
g.V().has("V1","userId", userId1).fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV("V1").property("userId", userId1)).as("a").iterate();
  g.V().has("V1","userId", userId2).fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV("V1").property("userId", userId2)).as("b").
  V().has("V1","userId", userId1).
  coalesce(outE("link").where(inV().as("b")),
           addE("link").to("b"))
```

comment: I used Neptune DB